# XML Data convert to SQL database,

Tags: mysql, schema, xml

I have an XML feed that i need to parse daily, i want to store all of the data from the XML feed in a SQL table so then that data can be queried and manipulated by my clients.

I can currently parse the XML data for select pieces of information for example the price of a product, but the pieces of data need to be user defined. I was wondering would it be possible to compare the XML data to a schema to allow me to find the names of each XML values.

Then i would be able to dynamically store the names of the XML values as attributes and the values of the XML data as a detail to that attribute, is there a way i can do this?

Will it have something to do with the schema that goes with the XML feed?

I would be using PHP to do this aswell

Thanks

James

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am currently using mysql

Comment: Is there a way does anyone know?